# Does Rek'Sai's Q have on hit proc?

Tags: league-of-legends

Do the attacks from Rek'Sai's Q also have on hit proc. eg. Hydra splash, red buff

Comment: Just read notes, I don't see anything that says they took away the on hit, just nerfed the DOT damage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes they do.**

Queen's Wrath is a self-targeted buff that applies on-hit effects.

But it does not empower the damage of Cleave (Hydra Splash) or Spell Blade

Comment: By empower you mean add to base damage of the on proc hit?

Comment: exactly! because it doesnt give you AD in anyform as a stat